# lua pattern matching: delimited captures

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lpeg

I am trying to parse a string such as: `&1 first &2 second &4 fourth \\`, and from it to build a table

```
t = {1=first, 2=second, 4=fourth}
```

I'm not very experienced with regex in general so my naive try (disregarding the `\\` and table parts for the moment) was

```
local s = [[&1 first &2 second &4 fourth \\]]

for k,v in string.gmatch(s, "&(%d+)(.-)&") do
    print("k = "..k..", v = "..v)
end
```

which gives only the first captured pair when I was expecting to see two captured pairs.  I've done some reading and found the `lpeg` library, but it's massively unfamiliar to me.  Is `lpeg` needed here?  Could anyone explain my error?

Comment: Try `s:gmatch'&(%d+)([^&]*)'`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Aha, thanks!.  Here `([^&]*)` is matching the longest sequence of characters not containing an `&` correct?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, there is a large text box under "add comment" where you can put your answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `&(%d+)(.-)&` matches `&1 first &`
2. Leaving `2 second &4 fourth \\` to be matched on
3. Your pattern does not match any further items

Comment: So the entire pattern is consumed once it is found.  It makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the values are one word, this should work:

```
string.gmatch(s, "&(%d+)%s+([^%s&]+)")
```

Take "&", followed by 1 or more digits (captured), followed by one or more space and then one or more non-space, non-& characters (captured).

Comment: Thanks Paul, the material to be captured is relatively arbitrary unfortunately.

Comment: Then you can follow @Egor's solution and strip trailing spaces (if need).